# Improving a convoluted math function in python

Tags: python, function, math, statistics, average

I would like to simplify the code below:

```
def function(data):
ss, s, n = reduce(lambda a, b: map(sum, zip(a,b)), [(x*x, x, 1) for x in data])
return (ss - s*s/n) / n
```

So far, I've figured out that ss, s, and n are the sum of the squared terms in data, the sum of the terms in data, and the number of terms in data respectively. Knowing this, I simplified the return statement to (Avg. of squared terms) - (Avg. squared). Is there a better way to simplify the code and get the same output? Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the *problem* with that code? What would you consider simpler? Do you understand what it does now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A beginner friendly implementation of the above code would be

```
def function(data):
#get sum of squares
    sum_of_squares = sum(i*i for i in data)
#get sum
    sum_of_items = sum(data)
#total elements
    total_elements = len(data)
#same func
```

Comment: `sum(i*i for i in data)` is faster as it does not create a list before calculating the sum.

Comment: Sure, see edit. Is the argument of sum considered a generator comprehension here? I'm a little confused by the lack of surrounding brackets etc

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - much appreciated